# plot the relation between RMSD and free energy

Tags: proteins, gromacs, peptide-shaker

how can i plot the relation between rmsd and free energy like the image i attached as i need to find the most stable conformation structure for my cycle peptide after finishing REMD simulation
[image]

Comment: I look at that graph and I note the high ∆G at 0 Ångström and wonder if the reference pose for the RMSD was not energy minimised correctly... so maybe not the best reference. http://prody.csb.pitt.edu/ is a helpful toolkit for this kind of analysis. Is Python an option and what is your reference? (If any user knowledgeable about peptides sees this please step in as I doubt I can help —NMR works by magic, right?)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment .. i'm trying to use the tool but couldn't .. in which part please i can plot RMSD with energy surface ?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to calculate the free energy along a trajectory and the rmsd along that trajectory and then cross-correlate/eliminate variables.  There may be a utility which does this but I am not ware of it.
https://manual.gromacs.org/current/user-guide/cmdline.html
There are two utilities of interest for doing just that.  See gmx_energy and gmx-rmsd.  Then you can plot one against the other by elimination of the time/space variables. Check out other calculations you can do with GROMACS:
https://manual.gromacs.org/current/user-guide/cmdline.html.